# Formulaa Convert Date format DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having an issue with `Datevalue` function cause it's not reading DD/MM/YYYY date format. It's giving `Error DATEVALUE parameter cannot be parsed to date/time.`

I tried changing the number format but the date should be reflecting DD/MM/YYYY cause it's from Australia.

Is there a formula that can change this date format?

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way is to change the Locale

File > Spreadsheet settings > Locale

[Google Help](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/UhSTVMQYhFw;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/authorid$3AAPn2wQdJ2V11yVrf5AzaY2HSNjzkUfwo7dINQlSoeZiJqECn0el9kT53ALji4tD4gdJcsdQUbc8J%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false)

Comment: Sometimes formula is better/easier. In one case, a client needed a "copy and paste" method because they would send weekly emails using GMass (and Google Sheets). They would export the data from Salesforce into Google Sheets and required a non-ambiguous date format that customers could receive. There are issues when converting dates when you change the locale (or at least there were for them).

Answer (score 3):

If the question is "How to convert DD/MM/YYYY format to MM/DD/YYYY format", then the answer is:

Assuming
Format of J2 is DD/MM/YYYY or D/M/YYYY
Format of output, K2 is MM/DD/YYYY or M/D/YYYY (depending on input).

```
K2 = date(right(J2,4),if(mid(J2,3,1) = "/",mid(J2,4,if(mid(J2,5,1) ="/",1,2)),if(mid(J2,2,1) = "/",mid(J2,3,if(mid(J2,5,1) = "/",2,1)))),if(mid(J2,2,1) = "/",left(J2,1),left(J2,2)))
```

Comment: You can use the SPLIT function to make this easier. I've produced it in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a formula to convert dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Much of the world date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` but US format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. One problem is that Google will recognize mm/dd/yyyy as a date ***and*** dd/mm/yyyy where dd < 13 (and interpret it wrong) ***but not*** dd/mm/yyyy where dd > 12 (it will then recognize the field as a text field).

The formula to convert dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy would be as follows (where A2 is the cell with the date in format dd/mm/yyyy):

```
=TEXT(CONCATENATE(
INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "/"), 1, 2), "/",
INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "/"), 1, 1), "/",
INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "/"), 1, 3)
), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

SPLIT(string, deliminator) will create an array from a string in a column/row format (like a spreadsheet).

INDEX(array, row, column) will grab a single value from the array. As we are only working with 1 row of data all the time "row" will be 1 and column will change. In this example, we are grabbing the second number (mm), then the first number (dd) and then the third number (yyyy).

CONCATENATE() puts these values into a single string so we end up with "mm/dd/yyyy".

TEXT(string, format) will format the string.

**NOTE:** You could remove the TEXT() function. However, using the TEXT function allows you to output the date in any format such as: "dddd mmmm d, yyyy" which would turn into Saturday January 1, 2022.

[image: Formula breakdown]

Comment: Beautifully suggested. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the locale.
I had a format of dd/mm/yy and I got it working with this

```
=ArrayFormula(datevalue("20"&right(F2:F,2)&"-"&mid(F2:F,4,2)&"-"&left(F2:F,2)))
```

if I have dd/mm/yyyy, I use this

```
=ArrayFormula(datevalue(right(F2:F,4)&"-"&mid(F2:F,4,2)&"-"&left(F2:F,2)))
```

where F is the column with the date.

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

It's simple as that.

Comment: What does it do? Nothing happens when I press that.